# I need to put a script in my file values.yaml is it possible?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

for example like this i need to put a script that retreive version from Chart.yaml file ( values.yaml is invalid and also it is not under the template folder

```
my-component:
  config:
    projectVersion:
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what this script would do?  How would you eventually use that value?  Are you in fact using [Helmfile](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io) as part of this setup, and if so, are the contents of the `helmfile.yaml` relevant to the question?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have a values.yaml that contains some config for  the microservices of the application and i want to pass a config to a microservice and this config is a variable that contains the version that exist in the Chart.yaml file.